# Tiles at zoom > 19 features are split / broken

Tags: leaflet, zooming, tile

In our project, we have a max zoom of 22 where the map is displayed through Leaflet.

Untill 18th zoom level, the tiles are formed properly.

Beyond that level , the map shows split routes as shown in attached figure: (The below link is when we have zoom level as 19 and so on)

**Screenshot**

[image: screenshot]

If I use `maxNativeZoom` as 18 and max zoom as 22, zoom happens 
but it blurs the tiles.

Comment: Most probably your raster tiles have been generated with this shift already. Check directly your tile images if they align properly without Leaflet.